# Converting to Powershell

Tags: regex, perl, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have this perl code I am trying to convert to powershell.

```
foreach my $f ( @file_list ) {
    if( $f =~ /^([\d]+)_${base_ver}_([\d]{4})\.zip$/i ){
        $pfile = $f;
        ( $pnum, $pdate ) = ( $pfile =~ /^([\d]+)_${base_ver}_([\d]{4})\.zip$/i ); # need to convert
        ( $pmon, $pyear ) = ( $pdate =~ /^(\d\d)(\d\d)$/ ); # need to convert
        if( ($patch_nbr == 0) || ($patch_nbr == $pnum) ) {
            $fcnt++;
        }
    }
}
```

I've converted most of it here..

```
$file_list = Get-ChildItem -force $base_dir
$file_list | foreach-object {
    if($_ -match "/^([\d]+)_${base_ver}_([\d]{4})\.zip$/i"){
        $pfile = $_


        if($patch_nbr -eq 0 -or $pacth_nbr -eq $pnum){
            $fcnt++
        }
    }
}
```

Not quite sure how to convert the two variables that equal the regex or if there is a better way to convert the perl code to powershell than what I already have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[mode]/pattern/[replace/][options]` syntax from `perl` doesn't apply to regex in PowerShell.

Thus, your pattern

```
/^([\d]+)_${base_ver}_([\d]{4})\.zip$/i
```

becomes

```
^([\d]+)_${base_ver}_([\d]{4})\.zip$
```

(`i` is unnecessary, `-match` resolves to `-imatch` (case-**i**nsensitive match) by default)

---

To capture the number prefix and date, you can use a named capture group (`(?<name>pattern)`):

```
^(?<num>[\d]+)_${base_ver}_(?<date>[\d]{4})\.zip$
```

You can then grab the match from `$Matches["name"]`:

```
if($f -match "^(?<num>[\d]+)_${base_ver}_(?<date>[\d]{4})\.zip$"){
    $pfile = $f
    $pnum = $Matches["num"]
    $pdate = $Matches["date"]
    $pmon = -join $pdate[0..1]
    $pyear = -join $pdate[2..3]
}
```

You could also change the regex pattern to capture the month and year individually:

```
if($f -match "^(?<num>[\d]+)_${base_ver}_(?<month>[\d]{2})(?<year>[\d]{2})\.zip$"){
    $pfile = $f
    $pnum = $Matches["num"]
    $pmon = $Matches["month"]
    $pyear = $Matches["year"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias R. Jessen! Helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I would put a `Where-Object` filter first. That allows you to use the `$matches` collection in the subsequent `ForEach-Object` without a second `-match` in a nested `if` statement. If you also change the date pattern from `(\d{4})` to `(\d{2})(\d{2})` you can assign `$pnum`, `$pmon`, and `$pyear` in a single statement. You could also simplify the condition for incrementing `$fcnt`. Instead of checking if `$patch_nbr` equals one of two values you could check if it's contained in an array of the two values.

```
Get-ChildItem -Force $base_dir |
  Where-Object { $_ -match '^(\d+)_${base_ver}_(\d{2})(\d{2})\.zip$' } |
  ForEach-Object {
    $pnum, $pmon, $pyear = $matches[1..3]
    if (0, $pnum -contains $patch_nbr) { $fcnt++ }
  }
}
```

Of course, if all you want to do is count the number of files matching a given patch number, you could just do something like this:

```
$f = Get-ChildItem -Force $base_dir | Where-Object {
       $_ -match '^(\d+)_${base_ver}_\d{4}\.zip$' -and
       0, $matches[1] -contains $patch_nbr
     }
$fcnt = @($f).Count
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Ansgar Wiechers! Saves me an extra line.  Also is there a way I can add a `?<date>`, so I capture the whole date along with `$pnum`, `$pmon`, `$pyear`?

Comment: @marc117 Sure. Simply change `(\d{2})(\d{2})` to `(?<date>(\d{2})(\d{2}))` to get a named group, or to `((\d{2})(\d{2}))` to get an additional unnamed group (so you can do the assignment like this: `$pnum, $pdate, $pmon, $pyear = $matches[1..4]`).

Comment: Thanks again @Ansgar Wiechers!